# Travelling Europe

Tags: word, knowledge

> Coming from Antwerp on the day Florin resigned, Louis and Evans
>   brother watched the match at the old forest lodge and with Louise, but
>   without Cécile, they visited the first movie of the day.

Question: what color is meant here?

Tip:

> Almost every word or combination of words in the sentence holds a clue to be found on the internet. Those clues have to be combined to find new clues, leading up to the answer.

Comment: It's my first one, so if something's wrong with it, I'll gladly hear.